# Automatically generating of type and reference to returned object for method using hot keys in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

How can I get the type automatically of returned object for method using hotkeys in **Intellij IDEA**?

Quite often there are times when you need to modify such line:

```
myinstance.getMyMethod();
```

in the following:

```
IMySomeObject mysomeobject = myinstance.getMySomeObject();
```

I wish that IDEA did it itself for me to save time. I do not wish to explore method's signature, find its returned type and manually create this reference with a specific type of returned object. It's not convenient.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the Introduce Variable refactor.

Select

```
myinstance.getMyMethod();
```

press <kbd><ctrl>+<alt> + V</kbd> and you will see a selections of names to give it like

```
IMySomeObject mySomeObject = myinstance.getMySomeObject();
```

I then select <kbd><Enter></kbd> as the first option is usually fine.

I suggest you have a look at all the refactoring tools in the Refactor Menu and learn what they all do.

---

You can type <kbd>m</kbd>

[image]

then type <kbd>.</kbd>

[image]

then <kbd><Enter></kbd>

[image]

then press <kbd><ctrl> + <alt> + V</kbd>

[image]

lastly press <kbd><Enter></kbd> to accept the default name.

Comment: BTW You can also introduce a (F)ield, a method (P)arameter and a new (M)ethod with similar keys.

Comment: You both may be interested to know you don't have to select it to introduce a variable.  Just put your cursor somewhere on that line.

Comment: @Daniel I would be very grateful if you would describe your advice more. Unfortunately I did not quite understand what you mean. I've put my cursor on the line `myinstance.getMyMethod();`, but nothing happens. Maybe I have to press `Ctrl`+`Space`, `Alt`+`Enter` or something else?

Comment: @MikeBrown I have added a step-by-step guide.

Comment: <alt> + <cmd> +  V for mac

Answer (score 2):

Another way besides `Introduce Variable` is by using their [postfix completion](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/postfix-completion/) feature.

The key thing is to type `.var` after the expression and then press the tab key.

Eg

```
myinstance.getMyMethod().var
```

With your cursor right after `.var`, press <kbd>ctrl + space</kbd>, and then press <kbd>tab</kbd> to select the suggestion. You'll then end up with:

```
IMySomeObject mySomeObject = myinstance.getMySomeObject();
```

btw, there's many more postfix completions options; I find it to be a very handy feature.